# Modify access to .htaccess to restrict directories based on user auth

Tags: .htaccess

Currently I have .htaccess to require user auth in order to proceed.

I'm trying to find a solution to restrict users from navigating to other /directory/ than the one assigned to their username (haven't figured out how to do it, yet).

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Welcome!"
AuthUserFile /home/public_html/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Order Deny,Allow
 Deny from all
 Allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
 Satisfy Any
<FilesMatch "^.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply do like : create a .htaccess file

```
 AuthName "Username and password required"
 AuthUserFile /home/path/.htpasswd
 AuthType Basic
 Require valid-user
 Order Allow,Deny
 Deny from all
 Allow from X.X.X.X/16
 Satisfy Any
```

if you have multiple file of .htpasswd then you can give multiple entry in .htaccess file like

```
AuthUserFile /home/will/.htpasswd
AuthUserFile /home/jone/.htpasswd
```

or

create .htaccess file and put in directory that you want to allow  . if you want to allow multiple directory then copy that .htaccess file in all directory . if you want deferent user can access different directory then edit .htaccess file of that particular directory . i think it will work for you  . for more  info [here](http://www.anchor.com.au/hosting/support/password_protection_using_htaccess)

Comment: Thanks, but I want them to be restricted in opening one directory, not 1 file, for example, user X be able to visit just domain.com/example not domain.com or domain.com/another-example.

Comment: i have changed answer i think it will help

Comment: hi ! if this is helpful for you then you can accept answer .